# MS Outlook 2016 - Add custom ribbon, that has 1 button and when clicked it executes a task

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, ribbonx

I've spent the last few days, trying various tutorials trying to accomplish the objective in the title. For the life of me, I keep hitting a brick wall. All of the searches return results for excel addins, or outlook.com addins.

Can someone recommend a tutorial (website, video, (step-by-step preferred) that outlines the process from start to finish?

I used to use macros, but the dread GPO disabled it so a addin looks like the next best option.

All I want to do is have a button appear on my ribbon, so I can select an e-mail, click the button and let the magic happen. If you have sample code that can at least get the custom button to display on the ribbon, I'm pretty sure I can figure out the rest.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you for reading. (if you made it this far.)

Comment: Dumb question, but why don't you go into outlook options and click the customize ribbon button?

Comment: @zhqiat, When I build & debug my project I can see it. (Listed under addins that I can add/remove) I enable it (check mark), but nothing shows up. I assume the code works, b/c the build did not fail and it's the same code I was using on 2010. Can't really test it, b/c I can't get the button to appear to trigger the execution.

Comment: Looks like you need to get the button added. Take a look at the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBA macros can't be used for customizing the ribbon in Outlook. You need to develop a COM add-in for that. For example, it can be a VSTO based add-in. See [Walkthrough: Creating Your First VSTO Add-In for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

VSTO provides two main ways for customizing the Ribbon UI (aka Fluent UI):

- [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Tab by Using the Ribbon Designer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386104.aspx)
- [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Tab by Using Ribbon XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942955.aspx)

As you can see VSTO provides a designer for creating a custom UI quicker. You can read more about the Fluent UI in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

From this [link](https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/macrobutton.htm#toolbar)

> In Outlook 2010 and Outlook 2013, things have been made a lot easier
>   as it allows you to manually customize the Ribbon as well.
>
> 1. Open the item window where you’d like to add the macro button to.
> 2. Select the tab where you’d like to add the macro button to.
> 3. Click the File button next to the Home tab and choose Options. Here, select the
>      section “Customize Ribbon”.
>      or
>      Right click any tab and choose
>      “Customize the Ribbon”. You’ll find the current tab already
>      highlighted and selected.
> 4. Create a New Group or even a New Tab to
>      place your custom button in. You cannot add your button to an existing
>      group.  You can use the Rename… button to give your group and/or tab a
>      nice name.
> 5. From the dropdown list “Choose commands from:” select:
>      Macros.  The list below will now show you all your macros.
> 6. Select the
>      macro that you wish to create a button for and press the Add >>
>      button.
> 7. To modify the name and icon press the Modify… button.
> 8. Close the Editor Options dialog to return to your
>      item window and use your button.